# Speed up MATLAB filter command

Tags: optimization, filtering, signal-processing, matlab

I am relatively new to using MATLAB filters. I am trying to filter a fairly large data set (about 2 million data points) using the following commands

```
rrc = rcosdesign(0.25, 10, floor(Fs/symRate), 'sqrt');
filtered = filter(rrc, 1, samples);
filtered = filtered / sqrt(floor(Fs/symRate));
```

When I run the MATLAB Profiler, it says the line

```
filtered = filter(rrc, 1, samples);
```

takes over 500 seconds to run. Any ideas on how to speed this up? I have tried using a FilterM function I found online ( http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32261-filterm ) but it takes the same amount of time. Anyone else have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few Ideas:

1. If you have FIR filter (As it seems from the code) you may gain performance using `conv2` which uses Intel IPP which might speed things up. Use the 'valid' flag to get `filter` results.
2. If the filter is long and the data is long, try using `xcorr` as it uses FFT to speed up correlations. Since you're after filtering, remember to flip your filter coefficients.
3. Compile `filterX` using Visual Studio 2013 or even better Intel C Compiler 2013 with optimization flags (`/03`). When using it, use the `filterX` command directly (Skip `FilterM` wrapper).
4. Use FFT manually to perform convolution.
5. Create a MEX version of Intel MKL / Intel IPP filter function.

Any of these should help considerably.